# java - how to parse String back to List of Map

Tags: java, string, list, parsing

I have a String with this format (it's a List of Map assigned to a string var)

```
[{code=1, data=Male} , {code=2, data=Female}]
```

.. how can I parse the above string back to list of map.. without using any String.split function (cause it is prone to error)

here is the code I've tried.. but with split function..

```
if(!string.equals("")){
                String[] listArray = string.split(DELIMITER);
                for (int i=0;i<listArray.length;i++) {
                    String val=listArray[i];
                    val = val.replaceAll("[\\{\\}]", "");

                    //Gets the value from DATA key
                    if(val.split(EQDELIMITER)[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("DATA")){
                        try{
                            map.put("DATA", val.split(EQDELIMITER)[1]);
                        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                            map.put("DATA", "");
                        }
                    }
                    //Gets the value from CODE key
                    if(val.split(EQDELIMITER)[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CODE")){

                        try{
                            map.put("CODE", val.split(EQDELIMITER)[1]);
                        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                            map.put("CODE", "");
                        }

                    }


                    if (map != null && map.size() >= 2) {
                        //add map to codeList
                        codeList.add(map);
                        map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what you tried so far? post the code

Comment: What do you mean String.split function is prone to error?

Comment: for example in DATA key I have a string with comma, the data would be also splitted

Comment: The input is JSON, you should be using a JSON parser, of which several are available.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JimGarrison do you have a sample code sir on how to do that? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are flexible enough to use a library, then Use  google's GSON

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
```

As you want a list of Map, wo you can also use TypeToken

```
List<Map<E,V>> list= new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, 
                           new TypeToken<List<Map<E, V>>() {}.getType());
```

replace E, V with actual types.

Comment: This is at best a comment.

Comment: should I use List.class since I need a List<Map<>>  ??

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for pointing out  have just updated the post

Comment: @SantoshJoshi I got an error...  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 14 path $[0].

Comment: @SantoshJoshi here is the syntax, I've used...  List<Map<String,Object>> sample= new Gson().fromJson(_listname, new TypeToken<List<Map<String,Object>>>() {}.getType());

Comment: @SantoshJoshi what part in my syntax??

Comment: ah ok I gets.. my JSON string..  but it's almost the same with the one I posted above..  [{code=1, data=Male} , {code=2, data=Female}]

Comment: do I need to use ..  new Gson().toJson() instead?

Comment: how that it was not valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125466/discussion-between-santosh-joshi-and-john1717).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go for object Mapper..?(`org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`)

it would be something like this...

```
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
Map<Integer,String> map = mapper.readValue(yourString,org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference.TypeReference<Map<Integer,String>>() {
});
```